# Windows 10 can't click on / unclickable apps links after searching in start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

PROBLEM:

[clicking the link does nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udQUq.png)

Does anyone know why?

Here's a similar thread with similar issue but none of the proposed solutions worked...
[Windows 10: Can't click on apps after searching in start menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1244869/windows-10-cant-click-on-apps-after-searching-in-start-menu?newreg=41857107ed234f43a586f712a2b325a8)

Comment: Do you have a question? We are not a blog site.

Comment: This is not how SU works.  You ask a question and someone answers it.  In rare cases, you post your own answer (AS AN ANSWER) after a period of time.  This is not how to get points for yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question also contains the answer to the question.  It should be closed, modified to NOT include the solution, and only then allowed to be answered.  The solution also is difficult to understand, so the “solution”, should be clarified.

Comment: @jpub - Why have you submitted a solution as a comment.  You need 10 reputation to answer a protected question.  The other question was protected due to extremely low quality answers that were deleted.  All we ask is you answer questions bu submitting an answer instead of asking a question and answering another question within the body of that question.

Comment: @Ramhound I spent time writing up the solution, and then clarifying it. Then editing the "question" and so forth to jump through the hoops of procedure. Now some process happy lotion in the basket mod has deleted all traces of the solution (even in the comments -- not trying to get "points" or whatever), *without allowing or taking the time to post the solution here or on the other thread?* that's pretty silly.

Comment: @jpub - You should not be submitting solution within a comment.  That is the reason your comments were deleted.  Your inability to answer a protected question is purposeful.  The question you want to answer has extremely low quality answers, in order to save the community work removing additional low quality answers, it was protected many many moons ago.  I believe a single upvote to a single contribution would give you the ability to answer a protected question.  **I reported** the commentary, since it was a solution to your question, we want answers that can be upvoted instead of commentary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is...

**For each "unclickable" search result, go to its original file location and 'pin to start' again.**

I found that in my case, there were some orphaned Start Menu items in the search results left over from Folder Redirection of "Start Menu" to a network share, and then disabling Folder Redirection.  None of the previous suggestions resolved the issue. The only thing that worked was this, which I assume updates the path/location entry for the filename that search has stored.

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87LW8.png)